# R: create a new df with conditional statement (related to row n and row n-1)

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with 1 column for participants and one column for my eeg triggers. Example:

| ID | trigger |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | SB |
| P1 | SB |
| P1 | resp |
| P1 | DH |
| P1 | Sc |
| P1 | resp |
| P2 | SB |
| P2 | resp |
| P2 | Sc |
| P2 | SB |

"resp" correspond to each time the participant has answered (pressed a button). If he answered after Sc, it is a **hit**, if he don't, it is a **miss**; if he answered after something else, it is a **false alarm** (fa); if he does not answer after something which is not Sc, it is a **correct rejection** (cr).

**I would like to create a new data frame and to have, for each participant the total number of Sc, the number of hit, of miss, of fa and of cr, like the following:**

| ID | Nb_Sc | hit | miss | fa | cr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 100 | 99 | 1 | 1 | 99 |
| P2 | 50 | 45 | 5 | 3 | 47 |

But i don't know at all how I could do that. Does anyone has an idea and can help?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this simple solution.

- All the `triggers` may be divided into two parts *actual triggers* say `Atrigger` (i.e. `!= 'resp'`) or ACTION and `responses` where `trigger == 'resp'` REACTION
- `participants` can `respond` on `Atrigger` ; so `Atrigger` + `resp` equals total row count per participant i.e. `n()`
- Now each `Atrigger` can be divided into two parts - `negatives` and `positives` ; `positives` where participant responded and `negative` where s/he didn't
- each `positive` & `negative` can be T/F according to the condition if action is true or false
- `Nb_Sc` is simply sum of `Sc` per group
- `hit` is simply sum of `resp` preceded by `Sc` **TRUE POSITIVES**
- `miss` is `Nb_Sc - hit` (if I am not wrong) **FALSE NEGATIVE**
- `fa` is sum of `resp` not preceded by `Sc` *(Again, if I am correct, sum of `fa` and `hit` should equal to number of `resp` per group)* **FALSE POSITIVES**
- `cr` is `actual triggers` - `sum(hit + miss + fa)` i.e. **TRUE NEGATIVES**

```r
df = structure(list(ID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
                           "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2"), trigger = c("SB", "SB", "resp", 
                                                                      "DH", "Sc", "resp", "Sc", "resp", "SB", "resp", "Sc", "SB")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                        -12L))
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Nb_Sc = sum(trigger == 'Sc'),
            hit = sum(trigger == 'resp' & lag(trigger) == 'Sc'),
            miss = Nb_Sc - hit,
            fa = sum(trigger == 'resp' & lag(trigger) != 'Sc'),
            cr = n() - (sum(trigger == 'resp') + hit + miss + fa))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  ID    Nb_Sc   hit  miss    fa    cr
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 P1        2     2     0     1     2
2 P2        1     0     1     1     1
```

---

On the [data by Sinh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985546/2884859) it gives this answer

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  ID    Nb_Sc   hit  miss    fa    cr
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 P1       21     4    17    23    25
2 P2       25     6    19    23    27
```

Comment: Yeah! I missed the `group_by` in the calculation

Comment: Dear @Anil, please, can you review the formula to calculate the number of `cr`? Using Sinh's data for `P1`, I have counted *manually* (just to be sure) 33 *true negatives* in line with Sinh's and mine computed results while your result shows only 25. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe, Sinh has already clarified that there may be two consecutive `resp` in his data, which I assumed is not the case.  Still, if you have such consecutive entries in your data, the answer can be modified to suit this.  and thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Anil! This is great! I changed `(trigger == 'Sc')' by `(grepl(".+c$", trigger) ==TRUE` and it works great on your examples of data (It still does not work on my data but obviously the problem comes from my data...).

Comment: @AdeLac74, use `sum((grepl(".+c$", trigger))` instead i.e. without `== TRUE`

Comment: @AnilGoyal, if I simply count the number of *false negatives* (`cr`) this number is completely independent of any consecutive `resp`. Unfortunately, your answer *requires* that there are *no* consecutive `resp` in the data and returns wrong counts for `cr` otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps, the consecutive `resp` can be removed by adding something like `filter(!(trigger == "resp" & lag(trigger) == "resp")) %>% ` before the `summarise()` statement.

Comment: @Uwe there can be many ways to remove consecutive `resp`  but the bigger question is do you have consecutive `resp` in your data?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(c("P1", "P2"), 200, replace = TRUE),
  trigger = sample(c("SB", "Sc", "resp", "DH"), 200, replace = TRUE)
)
```

```r
# Instead of look into previous row I look ahead based on value of current rows
df <- df %>%
  # added group_by here for correct calculated lead / lag
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
    # hit for all trigger ending with c follow by a resp
    grepl(".+c$", trigger) & lead(trigger, 1) == "resp" ~ "hit",
    # miss for all trigger ending with c not follow by a resp
    grepl(".+c$", trigger) & lead(trigger, 1) != "resp" ~ "miss",
    # fa for all trigger that not ending with c and follow b a resp
    !grepl("(.+c$)|(^resp$)", trigger) & lead(trigger, 1) == "resp" ~ "fa",
    # cr for all trigger that not ending with c and not follow by a resp
    !grepl("(.+c$)|(^resp$)", trigger) & lead(trigger, 1) != "resp" ~ "cr",
    TRUE ~ "No categorized yet"
  ))

# Here is what the data look like
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    trigger category          
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>             
#> 1 P2    Sc      miss              
#> 2 P1    Sc      miss              
#> 3 P2    SB      fa                
#> 4 P2    resp    No categorized yet
#> 5 P1    Sc      miss              
#> 6 P1    SB      cr

# all no categorized yet is for resp trigger which is accurate.
table(df$trigger, df$category)
#>       
#>        cr fa hit miss No categorized yet
#>   DH   39 14   0    0                  0
#>   resp  0  0   0    0                 56
#>   SB   27 18   0    0                  0
#>   Sc    0  0  10   36                  0
```

```r
# now summarized the data by ID
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Nb_Sc = sum(trigger == "Sc"),
    hit = sum(category == "hit"),
    miss = sum(category == "miss"),
    fa = sum(category == "fa"),
    cr = sum(category == "cr"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   ID    Nb_Sc   hit  miss    fa    cr
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 P1       21     4    17    15    33
#> 2 P2       25     6    19    17    33
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Updated the solution to match by regex**

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much! I have one more question: actually, the "Sc" could be "SBc" or "L1c" or "H1c" (anything ended by "c"). Is there a way to tell that in the code?

Comment: I just updated the solution to match by regex instead of character comparision

Comment: @SinhNguyen, still there are differences in both results.  I even set the seed same as yours?  Can you manually check for one participant at least then I will modify my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi Anil, the reasons for difference in our calculation is when there are `resp` that follow by another `resp`. Your calculation for that would result a `fa` while my calculation just ignore that `resp` as it only calculate based on the signal first. In the OP doesn't stated if a signal follow by multiple resp what should be count?. Noted that actual data may never have this case happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple for-loop in a function:

```
scan.reactions = function(df){
  out.id = c()
  out.nsc = c()
  out.hit = c()
  out.miss = c()
  out.fa = c()
  out.cr = c()
  for(resp in unique(df[,1])){
    out.id = c(out.id,resp)
    seq = c('',df[df[,1]==resp,2]) ## relevant sequence of events, leading with none
    out.nsc = c(out.nsc,sum(seq=="Sc"))
    lseq = c(df[df[,1]==resp,2],'')
    t = as.matrix(table(seq=="Sc",lseq=="resp")) ## Cross table of Sc and subsequent resp
    out.hit = c(out.hit,t[2,2]) ## True/True
    out.miss = c(out.miss,t[2,1])
    out.fa = c(out.fa,t[1,2])
    out.cr = c(out.cr,t[1,1])
  }
  return(data.frame("ID"=out.id,
                    "Nb_Sc"=out.nsc,
                    "hit"=out.hit,
                    "miss"=out.miss,
                    "fa"=out.fa,
                    "cr"=out.cr))
}
```

I changed your data slightly, so that there is one more correct reaction for P1 and tested it:

```
> df = structure(list(ID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2"), trigger = c("SB", "SB", "resp", 
"DH", "Sc", "resp", "Sc", "resp", "SB", "resp", "Sc", "SB")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

> df
   ID trigger
1  P1      SB
2  P1      SB
3  P1    resp
4  P1      DH
5  P1      Sc
6  P1    resp
7  P1      Sc
8  P1    resp
9  P2      SB
10 P2    resp
11 P2      Sc
12 P2      SB

> print(scan.reactions(df))
  ID Nb_Sc hit miss fa cr
1 P1     2   2    0  1  6
2 P2     1   0    1  1  3
```

It uses a cross table of `Sc` and subsequent `resp` and seems to produce the correct results.

Comment: why `P2` `cr` is 3?  He/she only missed one correctly i.e. last row??

Comment: There are four events, only one of them is an `fa`. So, the others must be `cr`.

Comment: So by this analogy why P1 cr is 6 and not 7?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, *data-driven* approach which uses a two dimensional *lookup table* to describe the *category* of two consecutive *triggers*. Subsequently, observed data are *joined* with the lookup table to categorize and count the sequence of events.

This approach

- avoids hardcoded `case_when()` statements or summation of hardcoded conditions
- covers all possible combinations of  two consecutive *triggers* thereby exhibiting gaps in the definition of *categories*
- is easily adapted to different definitions of *categories*

From the question and [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985205/r-create-a-new-df-with-conditional-statement-related-to-row-n-and-row-n-1#comment120164614_67985546) I understand that all values in `trigger` fall into one of three groups:

1. `resp` = participant has answered
2. `Sc` = triggers ending with the letter `c` like `Sc`, or `SBc`, `L1c`, `H1c`, etc
3. `other` = all other triggers which are neither `resp` nor ending with the letter `c`

With this simplification, we can define the categories of consecutive triggers as shown in the 2-D lookup table below:

|  | other | Sc | resp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| other | cr | cr | fa |
| Sc | miss | miss | hit |
| resp | NA | NA | NA |

Rows refer to the preceding trigger and columns to the subsequent trigger. So, `other` followed by `resp` belongs to category `fa` (false alarm).

`NA` indicates that this sequence is not categorized yet and should not be counted. The OP has not explicitely specified how to categorize trigger sequences after `resp` so I have deliberately chosen to ignore them to be in line with [Sinh Nguyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985546/3817004). But see below for how to modify the categorisation easily.

```
library(data.table)
# define categories
lut2D <- fread(
  "t1    other Sc   resp
   other cr    cr   fa
   Sc    miss  miss hit
   resp  NA    NA   NA"
)
# reshape to long format
lut1D <- 
  melt(lut2D, id.var = "t1", variable.name = "t2", value.name = "category", na.rm = TRUE)[
    # order categories as expected by the OP
    , category := factor(category, levels = c("hit", "miss", "fa", "cr", "dr"))][]
# prepare trigger values
tmp <- as.data.table(df)[
  # re-group trigger values: all values ending with "c" 
  trigger %like% "c$", trigger := "Sc"][
    # re-group trigger values: all other values 
    !trigger %in% c("Sc", "resp"), trigger := "other"][
      # create overlapping subsequences of length 2 in wide format 
      # and summaries per ID
      , .(t1 = head(trigger, -1L), t2 = tail(trigger, -1L),
          Nb_trig = .N, Nb_Sc = sum(trigger == "Sc")), keyby = ID]
# right join with lookup table to get matching categories, drop undefined categories
categorised <- lut1D[tmp, on = .(t1, t2), nomatch = NULL]
# count categories
dcast(categorised, ID + Nb_trig + Nb_Sc ~ category, fun = length)
```

With [Sinh Nguyen's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985546/3817004) we get

> ```
>    ID Nb_trig Nb_Sc hit miss fa cr
> 1: P1      96    21   4   17 15 33
> 2: P2     104    25   6   19 17 33
> ```

Please, note that I have added a count of trigger values `Nb_trig` per `ID`. So for `P1` 96 `trigger` values were recorded which yield 95 subsequences of length 2.

#### Additional explanations

- I have used `data.table` as I am more acquainted with it. `dplyr` & `tidyr` may work as well.
- The code uses `data.table`'s command chaining.
- The categorisation is applied on subsequences of length 2. In order to join the observed data and the lookup table both datasets have to be reshaped so that they include a column `t1` for the preceding trigger value and a column `t2` for the subsequent trigger value.
- Thus, the reshaped lookup table `lut1d` looks as follows

> ```
>       t1    t2 category
> 1: other other       cr
> 2:    Sc other     miss
> 3: other    Sc       cr
> 4:    Sc    Sc     miss
> 5: other  resp       fa
> 6:    Sc  resp      hit
> ```

- and the reshaped observed dataset `tmp` have become

> ```
>      ID    t1    t2 Nb_trig Nb_Sc
>   1: P1    Sc    Sc      96    21
>   2: P1    Sc other      96    21
>   3: P1 other    Sc      96    21
>   4: P1    Sc other      96    21
>   5: P1 other other      96    21
>  ---                             
> 194: P2 other other     104    25
> 195: P2 other other     104    25
> 196: P2 other  resp     104    25
> 197: P2  resp other     104    25
> 198: P2 other  resp     104    25
> ```

- After the join, the categorised observed dataset `categorised` is

> ```
>         t1    t2 category ID Nb_trig Nb_Sc
>   1:    Sc    Sc     miss P1      96    21
>   2:    Sc other     miss P1      96    21
>   3: other    Sc       cr P1      96    21
>   4:    Sc other     miss P1      96    21
>   5: other other       cr P1      96    21
>  ---                                      
> 140: other  resp       fa P2     104    25
> 141: other other       cr P2     104    25
> 142: other other       cr P2     104    25
> 143: other  resp       fa P2     104    25
> 144: other  resp       fa P2     104    25
> ```

- Note that undefined categories like
  `197: P2  resp other     104    25`
  have been dropped from the join result and are not counted.

#### Modifying the categorisation

The 2-D lookup table is easily modified. For instance, we can introduce a new category `dr` (duplicated responses) to cover cases where a participant has pressed the button two or more times in a row.

```
lut2D <- fread(
  "t1    other Sc   resp
   other cr    cr   fa
   Sc    miss  miss hit
   resp  NA    NA   dr"
)
```

With the modified categorisation and [Sinh Nguyen's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985546/3817004) we get

> ```
>    ID Nb_trig Nb_Sc hit miss fa cr dr
> 1: P1      96    21   4   17 15 33  8
> 2: P2     104    25   6   19 17 33  6
> ```

This result can help to explain the differences between [Sinh Nguyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985546/3817004) and [AnilGoyals's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986588/3817004) as discussed in [Sinh Nguyen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985205/r-create-a-new-df-with-conditional-statement-related-to-row-n-and-row-n-1#comment120170347_67985546).